# connectionString cannot be null error asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to asp.net and 3 tier architecture. I was able to build a web app only from MVC but when I tried 3 tier architecture I can't seem to use migration and I'm getting this error.

`System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')`

appsetting.json file

```
{
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=AdminLogin;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
},

"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
},
"AllowedHosts": "*"
```

}

AppConfiguration class

namespace GRIDevelopmentDAL.DataContex
{
internal class AppConfiguration
{

```
    public AppConfiguration()
    {
        var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "appsettings.json");
        configBuilder.AddJsonFile(path,false);
        var root = configBuilder.Build();
        var appSetting=root.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection");
        sqlConnectionString = appSetting.Value; 
    }
    public string sqlConnectionString { get; set; } 
}
```

}

DatabseContexFactory class

```
    namespace GRIDevelopmentDAL.DataContex
{
    public class DatabaseContexFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<DatabseContext>
    {
        public DatabseContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            AppConfiguration appConfig = new AppConfiguration();
            var opsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DatabseContext>();
            opsBuilder.UseSqlServer(appConfig.sqlConnectionString);
            return new DatabseContext(opsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
}
```

DatabseContext class

```
namespace GRIDevelopmentDAL.DataContex
{
    public class DatabseContext: IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
    {
        public class OptionsBuild
        {
            public OptionsBuild()
            {
                settings = new AppConfiguration();
                opsbuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DatabseContext>();
                opsbuilder.UseSqlServer(settings.sqlConnectionString);
                dbOptions = opsbuilder.Options;
            }
            public DbContextOptionsBuilder<DatabseContext> opsbuilder { get; set; }
            public DbContextOptions<DatabseContext> dbOptions { get; set; } 

            private AppConfiguration settings { get; set; }
        }

        public static OptionsBuild ops = new OptionsBuild();

        public DatabseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabseContext> options) : base(options) { }
        public DbSet<Admin> Admins { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you posted isn't 3-tier architecture. A DbContext doesn't need to store any kind of configuration. It's not a data layer either, it's a Unit-of-Work. What you did actually broke the separation offered by dependency injection. The DbContext constructor shouldn't be trying to read from the configuration in the first place. That's the job of `AddDbContext`. If any settings need to be supplied at runtime (why?) use the DbContextOptions constructor.

Comment: As for the `AppConfiguration` class - configuration is already abstract and decoupled. ASP.NET Core's configuration middleware allows you to load a strongly-typed config object and use it everywhere without knowing anything about the actual config middleware. The `AppConfiguration` class breaks this. Load the configuration data you want into an object and either register that object with DI, or pass it to any method that needs configuration settings. This way, your classes won't have to know where the settings came from

Comment: Config settings are also case sensitive.